# Renaming the tag [folgertechft-5] to separate company from model

Tags: support, tags

The tag [`[folgertechft-5]`](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tags/folgertechft-5/info) is about questions related to the `FT 5` by Folger Technologies. I'd like to request a rename so that the tag is [folgertech-ft-5] or [folgertech-ft5].

Answer (score 2):

Most of our other tags have a similar naming schedule: [aneta8](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aneta8), [aneta6](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aneta6), [aneta2](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aneta2). Once you fix that for 1, you need to do all. I do not think that will be necessary.

Furthermore, you can find the tag by entering e.g. `fol` or `ft`, in both cases the suggested tags show [folgertechft-5](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folgertechft-5).

Renaming is not recommended.

Comment: Good points, need to keep things consistent